# ffmpeg error SSL routines:ssl3_write_pending:bad write retry

Tags: ssl, ffmpeg, openssl

Recently, I see this error very often. Does anyone know what the error is and how to fix ? Please check full ffmpeg output here ( I already update openssl latest version from yum )

```
ffmpeg version N-93715-gd0e4d04 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)
  configuration: --prefix= ....
Input #0, mpegts, from '/tmp/4028813_video_0.ts':
  Duration: 00:04:08.19, start: 1.410111, bitrate: 1504 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 608x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 76:135], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101](eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 121 kb/s
[ sh: 2019-05-06  9:39:46 ]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/289693778580218?s_bl=1&s_sw=0&s_vt=api-s&a=Abxj1aU9OTqh0RtS':
  Metadata:
    comment         : gs4028813
    encoder         : Lavf58.27.103
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 608x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 76:135], q=2-31, 3000 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.52.100 aac
[ sh: 2019-05-06  9:39:47 ]size=     169kB time=00:00:00.52 bitrate=2643.9kbits/s speed=1.03x
......
[ sh: 2019-05-06  9:40:10 ]size=    3386kB time=00:00:22.72 bitrate=1220.7kbits/s speed=0.999x
[ sh: 2019-05-06  9:40:11 ]size=    3842kB time=00:00:25.32 bitrate=1242.9kbits/s speed=   1x
[tls @ 0x30ab3c0] error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)82 bitrate=1247.3kbits/s speed=   1x
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Input/output error
[flv @ 0x3030f80] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0x3030f80] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
Error writing trailer of rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/289693778580218?s_bl=1&s_sw=0&s_vt=api-s&a=Abxj1aU9OTqh0RtS: Input/output error
frame=  776 fps= 30 q=-1.0 Lsize=    3932kB time=00:00:25.82 bitrate=1247.3kbits/s speed=   1x
video:3530kB audio:406kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[tls @ 0x30ab3c0] error:1409F07F:SSL routines:ssl3_write_pending:bad write retry
```

Answer (score 0):

This error normally indicates a bug in the program calling OpenSSL. When an application using OpenSSL attempts to write application data to an SSL/TLS connection using the "SSL_write" function it may be unable to complete the write in one go (for example because the underlying network buffers are full). In this case a recoverable "retry" error occurs. The application is supposed to retry the write with exactly the same data as last time. If the calling application retries the write with *different* data then you get the "bad write retry" message (a fatal error). As to how to fix it that unfortunately depends on identifying the bug in the calling application and ensuring that retries are only ever performed with exactly the same data.